# Vanilla js equivalent of jquery .attr( attributeName, function )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I note that jQuery `.attr()` has a variant which allows you to set an attribute name to a function: see [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function).

I'm trying to find the plain vanilla js equivalent of this, but note that the `setAttribute()` function only appears to allow you to set an attribute value to a *string*: see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

More specifically, I'm trying to convert a snippet from [this article](https://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/) from jQuery to plain js:

```
$(function(){
  $('.stroke-double, .stroke-single').attr('title', function(){
    return $(this).html();
  });
});
```

Comment: I find it educational to look at the source code of libraries I use so I know what they're doing. [Here's the source for `attr`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/attr.js). If you look at the documentation you point to, you can see that sending a function calls that function for each element in the jQuery object, setting `this` to that element and setting the attribute to the result of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `.attr` with a function operates on each element in the query result. The equivalent would be something like

```js
function attrEquiv(selector, attr, setterFunction) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el, i) => {
    el.setAttribute(attr, setterFunction.call(el, i, attr)) // bind `el` to `this`
  })
}

attrEquiv('.stroke-double, .stroke-single', 'title', function(index, attr) {
  return this.innerHTML
})
```

---

ES5 version

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i) {
  el.setAttribute(attr, setterFunction.call(el, i, attr))
})
```

Comment: If you downvote (not you @drmrbrewer), please leave a comment so I can improve the answer

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote (the opposite), but I had to adapt it slightly to work also in phantomjs (I'm running this both in modern Chrome and a slightly ancient phantomjs... your answer worked in Chrome but choked in phantomjs).  I removed the double arrow notation and used a traditional `for` loop instead of `forEach`.  Really helpful answer, though.

Comment: Ah yeah, `NodeList.prototype.forEach` and arrow functions are still relatively new. I'll update the answer with some alternatives